# Yii url-manager : file with a point (sitemap.xml)

Tags: php, url, yii, yii-url-manager

I have a file with a point (sitemap.xml) and Controller Sitemap with action Index. Via url-manager i create patten:

```
'/sitemap.xml' => '/sitemap/index',
```

i try

```
'sitemap' => array('sitemap/index', 'urlSuffix' => '.xml'),
```

and still writes an error 404. I'm doing wrong, please tell me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
'/sitemap.xml'=>array('sitemap/index', 'urlSuffix'=>false),
```

Comment: `code`'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
                'rules' =>  array('<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            )),`code`

Comment: Did you [hide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/) an `index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
rules = array(
'sitemap.xml/*' => '/sitemap/index',

 '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
),
```